# Bedeutung von "Einen Kasten machen"

Tags: meaning, slang, colloquial

In dem Lied "*Nylon*" ([Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Isb8hkuMAoI&pxtry=1),[Text](http://www.justsomelyrics.com/1805557/afrob-nylon-lyrics.html)) vom Sänger Afrob taucht die Phrase "einen Kasten machen" auf, deren Bedeutung sich mir nicht erschließt. Kontext ist:

> er wollte es beweisen und im Wettbewerb nicht kneifen, er sagt er macht
>   einen Kasten, Junge bleib bei deinen Leisten, damit fiel er auf die
>   Schnauze und verkroch sich tagelang,

Vom Kontext klingt das nach einer Bezeichnung für eine Art krimineller Handlung, aber welcher? Oder ist das eine Bezeichnung für einen Kasten Bier alleine leeren?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hier spricht insbesondere der Hintergrund des Hip-Hop-Künstlers selbst: Es ist in den Kreisen üblich eine "Beatbox zu machen", entweder als Untermalung oder eigene Performance. So findet sich die "box" umgangssprachlich und eingedeutscht als Kasten wieder. Für weitere Informationen siehe auch [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hip-Hop_%28Subkultur%29#Beatboxing).